# Iterating through/making calls to a LinkedList of Custom Linked Lists

Tags: java, iterator, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm having a bit of trouble iterating through and how to call the linked list, and just using a LinkedList of linked lists.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
LinkedList<MyLinkedList<Integer>> l = new LinkedList<MyLinkedList<Integer>>();
MyLinkedList<Integer> m = new MyLinkedList<Integer>();

m.add(1);
l.add(m);
```

Here is the Iterator class, NOTE: This is for a doubly linked list, I'm also trying to figure out how to turn it into a singly linked list iterator. 
http://pizza.unbsj.ca/~owen/backup/courses/3323-2007/MyLinkedList.java

How do I call/use the iterator class, and is there any way to change that into a singly linked list iterator? I dont get how the iterator works with the main class in this case.

Comment: You should ask your teacher for help understanding this homework

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code to find the bugs in the code.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am short on time.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is how you would call it:

```
java.util.Iterator<Integer> myIterator =  m.iterator( )
```

If you want to know more about how the `Iterator` class works, read [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: That is throwing the following errors: 
Change Modifier of iterator to static which does not work as that cannot be static, and 2 Infer Generic type arguments. 
Could you please explain your answer a bit more as I have very limited understanding of this iterator class

Comment: @TheGandhi I mistyped earlier.  See edit